# DLL (Absolute) Basics in C

Tags: c, dll

I've always wanted to learn how to manipulate .DLLs. I looking for tutorials, but I couldn't find a single one that can explain everything to me line-by-line. If there is a chance that I would find something, it wouldn't be in C (I'm looking for C tuts. Not C++ ones.)

Comment: What kind of manipulation?  Moving files around?  Swapping one library with another?  Run-time loading of a DLL and calling functions in it?  Creating DLLs for others to use?

Comment: Your question is entirely too vague. There are many interpretations of "manipulate", and none of them is clear when you're asking about DLLs. In addition, this site is not a link referral source, and the [help/on-topic] clearly states: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.".

Comment: Nothing specific. To start with, I really don't know how they work. All I know is that they could serve as a library that can contain functions. What I don't know is how I can create one. Are there special keywords or even more languages that I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

I will explain in a general way how they work here. For the whole story, start at the [MSDN documentation of DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also read documentation for your C compiler for the specific details about how to create and use them. And when you have trouble, ask specific questions at SO with supporting code so we can be more helpful.

At the simplest level (and deliberately omitting details) a DLL is a collection of functions that can be loaded into a process's memory space at run time with [`LoadLibrary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and subsequently called by the process.

The DLL file itself is formatted like a normal Windows executable file, but it does not have `WinMain` or `main` and as a result cannot be invoked without a container process. So it is created with the linker, just like any other executable. (This is a small lie. There actually is an entry point called [`DllMain()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it is used for advanced features, is called when the DLL is loaded and unloaded, and still doesn't allow a DLL to be invoked directly from the command prompt or "executed" by [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or similar API calls.)

DLLs can be loaded automatically at run time. This is the most common form, and allows the C runtime library to be loaded by every program from a single common copy. To do this, you simply link the application with the right libraries and options, and the system takes care of loading the DLL and fixing up all symbols that point into it.

DLLs can also be loaded at run time. This is commonly done to allow extensions to an existing application. One classic example of this is a Windows screen saver. A .SCR file is really just a renamed DLL that exports certain functions that provide the features of the screen saver. The window manager looks up which screen saver is configured at run time, load its .SCR file as a DLL, and calls the functions it provides.

You load a DLL by calling `LoadLibrary()`, and you find out the addresses of functions it contains with with [`GetProcAddress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note that it is entirely the responsibility of the calling application to know how to call the function, and there are lots of interesting ways that can go wrong. The most obvious case is that you *must* provide the expected number of parameters of the right types expected by the function in the DLL.

One of the reasons that COM was invented was to provide a framework that would allow the DLL to describe what functions it offers and the application to ask what parameters are expected by any particular function. The .NET framework provides the same sorts of introspective features but in many ways much more successfully. None of that sort of protection is available (another lie, it is, but it is *very* tricky to implement COM in pure C) to a plain C program and a DLL written in plain C.